# Problems with builder pattern in Python

Tags: python, pygame, builder

I want to create a User Fish and Enemy Fish from the same base class Fish. However, as I learned, with this code below when I try to change the Enemy Fish attributes, my User Fish attributes end up changing as well:

```py
# base class
class Fish(object):
    def __init__(self, type="None", size=(1, 1), position=(1, 1), speed=1,
                 direction=1):
        self.type = type
        self.size = size
        self.position = position
        self.speed = speed
        self.direction = direction

    def draw(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

# user fish builder: generates new user fish
class Create_User_Fish(Fish):
    Fish.type = "User"
    Fish.size = (150, 100)
    Fish.position = (20, 200)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(DISPLAYSURF, BLUE, (Fish.position, Fish.size))

# enemy fish builder: generates new enemy fish
class Create_Enemy_Fish(Fish):
    Fish.type = "Enemy"
    Fish.size = (150, 100)
    Fish.position = (750, 200)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(DISPLAYSURF, BLUE, (Fish.position, Fish.size))

# snippet of calls I make before running my game
Player = Create_User_Fish()
Player.draw()
```

When I change the `Fish.position` under the class `Create_Enemy_Fish`, this changes the `Fish.position` of my `User` Fish too. Tips?

Comment: `Fish` is `Fish`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes in the object `Fish` like `self.type`, `self.size` are [instance attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects), but there are additional [class attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) set to the class `Fish` like `Fish.type`, `Fish.size`, ... (The assignment of thes attributes is done in after `class Create_User_Fish` respectively `class Create_Enemy_Fish`). The class attributes exists only once in the class `Fish`, the 2nd writing overwrites the 1st one.

You've to add a constructor to the classes `Create_User_Fish` respectively `Create_Enemy_Fish` and to do a [`super()` call](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance) to the constructor of the inherited class `Fish`, to set the instance attributes. Us the instance attributes in the method `draw`:

```py
class Create_User_Fish(Fish):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("User", (150, 100), (20, 200)) 

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(DISPLAYSURF, BLUE, (self.position, self.size))
```

```py
class Create_Enemy_Fish(Fish):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Enemy", (150, 100), (750, 200)) 

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(DISPLAYSURF, BLUE, (self.position, self.size))
```

Comment: actually, no class level attribute are set in either `Create_User_Fish` nor `Create_Enemy_Fish`. those are simply assgnment statements that modify the `Fish` class attributes and don't affect the class namespace at all of the class block they are executed in.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh, I see what you mean. I've changed that.